# When is type checking for type argument performed?

Tags: c++, templates, programming-languages, computer-science, generic-programming

Here is some C++ template code from Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott

```
template<typename T>
class chooser {
    public:
    virtual bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename C>
class arbiter {
    T* best_so_far;
    C comp;
public:
    arbiter() { best_so_far = nullptr; }
    void consider(T* t) {
        if (!best_so_far || comp(*t, *best_so_far)) best_so_far = t;
    }
    T* best() {
        return best_so_far;
    }
};

class case_sensitive : chooser<string> {
public:
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) { return a < b; }
};
...
arbiter<string, case_sensitive> cs_names; // declare new arbiter
cs_names.consider(new string("Apple"));
cs_names.consider(new string("aardvark"));
cout << *cs_names.best() << "\n"; // prints "Apple"
```

> the C++ compiler will create a new instance of the `arbiter`
>   template every time we declare an object (e.g., `cs_names`) with a
>   different set of generic arguments. **Only when we attempt to use such
>   an object (e.g., by calling `consider`) will it check to see whether the
>   arguments support all the required operations.**
>
> Because **type checking is delayed until the point of use**, there is nothing magic
>   about the `chooser` class. If we neglected to deﬁne it, and then left it out of the
>   header of `case_sensitive`, the code would
>   still compile and run just ﬁne.

Are the following two time points at compile time or run time:

- the time "when we attempt to use such an object" and
- "the point of use"?

Does "type checking is delayed until the point of use" mean that the type checking is done at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - the time "when we attempt to use such an object" and
> - "the point of use"?

Both refer to the source code, not to runtime.

In this line:

```
arbiter<string, case_sensitive> cs_names;
```

the compiler sees a `std::string` and `case_sensitive`, and tries to implement a version of `arbiter` with `T` replaced by `std::string` and `C` replaced by `case_sensitive`.

If you define another `arbiter` with other types, a new version of `arbiter` will be generated and compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Alain has the right of it.

For future reference C++, in general, compile-time checks everything. The only exceptions I know of are dynamic casting of polymorphic types and the function typeid, which returns the type of an object.

In my opinion if you are ever using those functions you should usually rethink your O-O design. (or you are trying to fix someone else's broken code without refactoring).