# Why can't a generic interface be used as a type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, programming-languages, computer-science, generic-programming

Here is some Java Generic code from [Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124104099/content/Sections%20and%20Sub-sections/Scott%204e_Supplementary%20Sections.pdf)

```
interface Chooser<T> {
    public boolean better(T a, T b);
}
class Arbiter<T> {
    T bestSoFar;
    Chooser<? super T> comp;

    public Arbiter(Chooser<? super T> c) {
        comp = c;
    }
    public void consider(T t) {
        if (bestSoFar == null || comp.better(t, bestSoFar)) bestSoFar = t;
    }
    public T best() {
        return bestSoFar;
    }
}

class CaseSensitive implements Chooser<String> {
    public boolean better(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b) < 1;
    }
}
...
Arbiter<String> csNames = new Arbiter<String>(new CaseSensitive());
csNames.consider(new String("Apple"));
csNames.consider(new String("aardvark"));
System.out.println(csNames.best()); // prints "Apple"
```

> Java requires that the 
>    code for each generic class be manifestly (self-obviously) type safe, independent of any particular instantiation. This means that the type of ﬁeld `comp`—and in
>   particular, the fact that it provides a `better` method—must be statically declared.
>   As a result, the `Chooser` to be used by a given `Arbiter` instance must be speciﬁed
>   as a constructor parameter; it cannot be a generic parameter.  (We could have used
>   a constructor parameter in C++; in Java it is mandatory.)

1. What does "code for each generic class be manifestly
   (self-obviously) type safe, independent of any particular
   instantiation" mean?
2. Why does it lead to the conclusion that "the type of ﬁeld `comp`—and
   in particular, the fact that it provides a `better` method—must be
   statically declared"?
3. What does "statically declared" mean? What is it opposed to?
4. What is it like when `Chooser` were used as a generic parameter in Java
   (even though it is not correct)?  I just want to see what it looks
   like to be wrong  in Java.  Does "We could have used a constructor parameter
   in C++; in Java it is mandatory" mean that the wrong way would be
   written in C++ way (I saw similar code in C ++ earlier in the book, which I quoted [in a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46002465/156458))? Is the following the wrong code in Java, implied by "`Chooser`     cannot be a generic parameter":

   ```
   class Arbiter<T, Chooser> {
       T bestSoFar;
       Chooser comp;

       public Arbiter(Chooser c) {
           comp = c;
       }
       public void consider(T t) {
           if (bestSoFar == null || comp.better(t, bestSoFar)) bestSoFar = t;
       }
       public T best() {
           return bestSoFar;
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: "it cannot be a generic parameter" It cannot be a generic parameter of what?

Comment: A generic parameter of `Arbiter`, I guess, compared to a similar code in C++ earlier in the book. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46002465/156458

Comment: I am entirely missing the point of this quote. I don't see a problem here...

Comment: I mean, you can't declare `class Arbiter<T, Chooser> {`, because then `Chooser` is a type variable, not the `Chooser` interface.

Comment: Do you mean a  interface can be used as a type parameter ?

Comment: A type parameter can't be an interface, or a class. It's neither thing: a type variable is a concept in its own right.

Comment: You misunderstood. I am  not saying they are the same concept, but one is used as another. See my updated edit of my comment.

Comment: What's a "type interface"?

Comment: I meant interface. in my post `Chooser` is   a generic interface. corrected

Comment: Of course it can. `List<List<Serializable>>` is entirely valid, but only uses interfaces as the type parameters.

Comment: Ok. Then my part 4: "What is it like when `Chooser` were used as a generic parameter (even though it is not correct)? ..."

Comment: Type variables just can't be parameterized. It's got nothing to do with whether there's an interface with the same name as the type variable: declaring `<Chooser>` hides the name `Chooser` (as in the interface), so `Chooser` then refers to the type variable, not that interface.

Comment: From [JLS Sec 4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5): "A parameterized type is a class or interface type of the form C<T1,...,Tn>, where C is the name of a generic type and <T1,...,Tn> is a list of type arguments that denote a particular parameterization of the generic type.". `C` has to be a class or an interface.

Comment: do you mean `T1,...,Tn` in `C<T1,...,Tn>`  can't be generics themselves? the quote from  you doesn't say so.

Comment: The restrictions on the type arguments of parameterized types are given in the next section, [JLS Sec 4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1). TL;DR: yes, `T1` etc can be generic.

Comment: The discussion in the comments seems to me unrelated to the question. I'm afraid to write an answer on grounds that I'm missing the whole point. If Indeed I'm so off, maybe you could explain the connection between the question and this discussion?

Comment: @user1803551 answer away. I feel like I've totally misunderstood this question, because I'm still unsure about what is being asked.

Comment: @AndyTurner How does "C has to be a class or an interface" relate in the example here?

Comment: @user1803551 Please feel free to answer. Thanks. Andy and I  were just talking about part 4 of my post, and I feel we were a bit off. Please ignore what we were saying here.

Comment: @Tim in the second block of code, `Chooser` isn't a class or interface in `Chooser<? super T>` - it's a type variable - so it can't be used in a parameterized type declaration.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks. I see. I change `Chooser<? super T>` to `Chooser` in the definition of `Arbiter` in the second block of code, and will that work with the rest of the code in the first block of code?

Comment: No, because the type variable `Chooser` is upper-bounded by `Object`. In other words, you could only invoke methods that you would find an `Object` (like `toString`), because it could be an instance of any reference type (e.g. String, Integer, MyClass, your `Chooser` interface; but not int, float, double etc). It would be a compiler error to invoke `better`.

Comment: I was more than halfway through writing an answer when I consulted a C++ dev and we agreed, based upon the comparison that the writer makes, that the writing is confusing at best. Some of the comparison is not specific to generics/templates, the terms he uses are not well-defined, and in some cases there is actually no contrast in the comparison, as he tries to show. I would go with the official generics tutorials from Oracle instead.

Answer (score 2):

Quick disclaimer: I don't know C++ anywhere near as well as I know Java. If I did get something wrong in this answer I'm happy to correct it.

Most of the questions here can be answered by explaining the important difference between Java generics and C++ templates. Java generics are implemented with type erasure which means that the compiler transforms generic code in to non-generic code by removing references to generics and inserting casts where appropriate. So for example, we might have generic code as follows:

```java
class Holder<T> {
    private T obj;
    Holder(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }
    T get() { return obj; }
}

Holder<String> h = new Holder<String>("hello");
String s = h.get();
```

And during compilation that's transformed in to code which is more like this:

```java
class Holder {
    private Object obj;
    Holder(Object obj) { this.obj = obj; }
    Object get() { return obj; }
}

Holder h = new Holder("hello");
String s = (String) h.get();
```

By contrast, C++ templates are more like a very sophisticated copy and paste. We might start with code like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class holder {
    T obj;
public:
    holder(T obj) : obj(obj) {}
    T& get() { return obj; }
};

holder<std::string> h{"hello"};
std::string& s = h.get();
```

And when we do `holder<std::string>`, the compiler actually creates a new class (called a template instantiation) which has `T` replaced with `std::string`:

```cpp
class holder_std_string {
    std::string obj;
public:
    holder_std_string(std::string obj) : obj(obj) {}
    std::string& get() { return obj; }
};
```

The major implications of this are:

1. Each template instantiation actually "knows" what its type argument is inside its class body.
2. The compiler can generate different code for different template instantiations.

For example, you might observe that in the following method of the C++ `arbiter`:

```cpp
void consider(T* t) {
    if (!best_so_far || comp(*t, *best_so_far)) best_so_far = t;
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ note!
}
```

The method body expects that the template argument to `C` has an operator overload for `()`, but there's nothing about the template declaration which indicates this. Instead, C++ basically has duck typing via templates. The template instantiation for `arbiter<string, case_sensitive>` actually knows that its template argument is `case_sensitive` and can therefore generate code which calls the overloaded `()` operator. We can pass anything as a template argument as long as it has an overloaded `()` operator which is compatible with the expression which calls it. If you passed some argument to `C` which didn't have an overloaded `()` operator, the template instantiation would fail to compile.

Another interesting note about the C++ code is that you didn't need to pass a `case_sensitive` object to a constructor because the template instantiation actually knows how to default construct one itself.

For your question #4, making the `Chooser` type a generic parameter in Java would be like this:

```java
class Arbiter<T, C extends Chooser<? super T>> {
    T bestSoFar;
    C comp;

    public Arbiter(C c) {
        comp = c;
    }
    public void consider(T t) {
        if (bestSoFar == null || comp.better(t, bestSoFar)) bestSoFar = t;
    }
    public T best() {
        return bestSoFar;
    }
}
```

However, note that we've accomplished this via the bounded type variable `C extends Chooser<? super T>` which tells the compiler that `C` must actually be some subtype of `Chooser`. This is how the compiler knows that it's possible for us to call the method `comp.better(...)` and what method this expression refers to. Remember there's only ever one `Arbiter` class in Java so all generic `Arbiters` need to share bytecode.

The C++ code has no such requirement because the validity of the expression `comp(...)` is decided during instantiation of the template.

> What does "statically declared" mean? What is it opposed to?

In this context it just means that it's known at compile-time. To illustrate:

```java
// We know statically (at compile-time)
// that n is some type if Number.
void m(Number n) {
    // We could determine at runtime what
    // the actual type of n is a couple
    // of different ways.
    if (n instanceof Double)
        /* n is actually a Double */;
    // Prints the actual type of n.
    System.out.println(n.getClass());
}
```

Types in C++ are statically-known too. It's just that C++ templates are implemented in a way that allows for many things that Java generics don't allow.